# How to code the NOT IN query in Hibernate criteria?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

This is the query that I am trying to write in Criteria:

```
    SELECT * FROM abc 
    WHERE NOT PartType IN ('0','4','5','6','7','a','b','c')
```

The above is in iBatis.

So this is the hbm.xml for the table

```
  <class name="Parts" table="SomeDb..Parts">
        <id name="recordNumber" column="Recnum" />
        <property name="partNumber" column="Partnum" />
        <property name="sectionNumber" column="Secnum" />
        <property name="articleNumber" column="Articlenum"/>
        <property name="headerNumber" column="Headernum"/>
        <property name="partType" column="PartType"/>
        <property name="code" column="Code"/>
  </class>
```

The partType is nvarchar with the length of 1 in a SQL Server db.
I am trying to select records that do not have a part type of any of this '0','4','5','6','7','a','b','c'.
Hope I have answered your question.
Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying? How does the table look like which datatype has the field PartType?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```java
Criteria criteria = ...;
criteria.add(
  Restrictions.not(
    Restrictions.in("partType", new String[] {"0","4","5","6","7","a","b","c"})
  )
);
```

Comment: I got it to work with this : \n      criteria.add(Expression.not(Expression.in("paraType", new String[]{"0", "4", "5", "6", "7", "a", "b", "c"}))); \n I will try your solution too !! Thanks !!

Comment: Expression is deprecated now, you should use Restrictions instead as specified in the answer.